# How to do a Confirmation popup for deleting of MySQL database entry?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm wanting to make a confirmation popup for when I click to delete an id from a database which either continues running the script and deletes the id (YES) or cancels the script and goes back (NO).

I need solution in JavaScript and PHP.

Here Is My Code Link. Please check and give me solution

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2lSiCcdmUf-WDM3SWQzc29sdGM?usp=sharing

Comment: Please show your code, What you have tried?

Comment: @SanchitGupta : Please give me a Demo because I have many file so I can't upload so, If you give me just demo for that then it's better.

Thanks

Comment: @SanchitGupta Here is my code
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2lSiCcdmUf-WDM3SWQzc29sdGM?usp=sharing

Comment: @ HardikChapla let me check.

Comment: @SanchitGupta : Thanks

Comment: You are using mysql extension which deprecated in php 5 and removed from php 7. Please update your code with mysqli.

Comment: Okay thank you @SanchitGupta

Comment: Also in the `display.php` if you want to prompt a confirmation when user click on the delete button, please update your code like `echo "<td><a onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure?\")' href='remove.php?id=1'>Delete</a></td>";`

Comment: @SanchitGupta : Thank You Bro. It's Work

echo "<td><a onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure?\")' href='remove.php?id=$row[id]''>Delete</a></td>";

Comment: Your Welcome @ Hardik Chapla. But Please update your code.

Comment: Yes @SanchitGupta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have created a file to delete specific record. In the anchor tag just pass the **url** to that file with specific **record id**. Add **onclick** to **a tag** to prompt a confirmation.

```
<a href="DELETE_PAGE_URL?id=record_id" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" >Delete Record</a>
```

For more detail [**Javascript Confirm()**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)

If you need further assistance there are lots of php CRUD tutorial on the web.
[**PHP CRUD TUTORIAL**](https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/php-crud-tutorial-part-1)

Hope it will help

Comment: echo "<td><a onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure?\")' href='remove.php?id=$row[id]''>Delete</a></td>";

Comment: yes this answer help for me and I have replaced with old code.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 and also remove your google drive url from public

Answer (score 1):

Only Javascript is here of sense

```
var r = confirm("You want to delete an user! are you sure?");
if (r == true) {
    // request php script on server to delete an id
} else {
    // you do nothing here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a on click function

```
   <input type="button" Onclick="delete()">

    function delete(){
    var result = confirm("Are you want to delete");
    if (result) {
        //delete the item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery UI for confirmation dialog. Don't use javascript confirmation alert you can't design it. So better is use jQuery UI you can design it base on you site theme. See this [link](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) you can understand source code easily.

Answer (score -1):

```
https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/
for more beautiful alerts 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
      swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
      },
       function(isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
          swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
        } else {
          swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
        }
      });
    });
});
</script>
```